# How can you get all the number of distinct values for each field in a table?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to get all the cardinalities in one go for all fields in a table?

There is a way to get the cardinality of one field:

```
SELECT count(distinct year) AS unique_year_cnt FROM default.flight_data_s3;
```

That returns:

Sample data:

```
presto:default> select * from default.flight_data_s3 limit 10;
 year | month | day | day_of_week | dep_time | crs_dep_time | arr_time | crs_arr_time | unique_carrier | flight_num | tail_num | actual
------+-------+-----+-------------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+----------+-------
 2008 |    12 |  12 |           5 |     1301 |         1305 |     1520 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N4YAAA   |
 2008 |    12 |  13 |           6 |     1302 |         1305 |     1518 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N4XTAA   |
 2008 |    12 |  14 |           7 |     1302 |         1305 |     1554 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N438AA   |
 2008 |    12 |  15 |           1 |     1306 |         1305 |     1549 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N4WWAA   |
 2008 |    12 |  16 |           2 |     1324 |         1305 |     1605 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N4YGAA   |
 2008 |    12 |  17 |           3 |     1300 |         1305 |     1513 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N4XFAA   |
 2008 |    12 |  18 |           4 |     1300 |         1305 |     1544 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N435AA   |
 2008 |    12 |  19 |           5 |     1305 |         1305 |     1530 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N4YRAA   |
 2008 |    12 |  20 |           6 |     1324 |         1305 |     1544 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N435AA   |
 2008 |    12 |  21 |           7 |     1318 |         1305 |     1513 |         1510 | AA             |       1715 | N595AA   |
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Treat your first query as a starting point and add more stuff to the select clause.

Comment: Can you clarify the question little bit more? Do you want the count of unique rows?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.